# No access to Workflow Page after registering Workflow manager 2013 to a sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow-manager, workflow-manager-farm

After I registered workflow manager with a site collection, users are not able to view the workflow start page. The message "no access to site collection" is displayed.

What should be done?

Answer (score 0):

Does the workflow work normally?

Here are some troubleshooting steps:

1. Make sure the Workflow Manager farm is running. And make sure the workflow service is connected to SharePoint.
2. Disable loopback check.
3. Created a new scope and register the workflow service using Register-SPWorkflowService.

In addition, try to add Workflow service account as “WFServiceOperators” into the database(WFInstanceManagementDB and WFResourceManagementDB), you can follow below steps:

1. Open the Query Window and Select the database “WFInstanceManagementDB”
2. Write the following line of script:

   GRANT EXECUTE TO WFServiceoperators
3. Hit Execute.
4. Repeat the steps for database "WFResourceManagementDB".
5. Confirm the error message has disappeared and cpu usage is down to normal.
6. Confirm Workflow status page in SharePoint site is working as expected.